# Backbone fetch an object

Tags: php, backbone.js

I have an app in backbone.
In this app I fetch a json stored into my server.
For some reason now I don't want to fetch json from file but from an array  (same structure that Json) passed from PHP.
Ho can I change my code to do the same thing?
This is my app

```
var CombinationView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    template: _.template($("#hotel-list-template").html()),
    initialize: function(){ 
        this.list = new HotelCollection([], { 
            url: 'includes/list.json' 
        }); 

        this.list.on("sync", this.listLoaded, this); 

        this.list.fetch(); 
    }, 
    render: function(){ 
        this.$el.html('Loading...'); 
        return this; 
    }, 
    listLoaded: function(){ 
        //code
    }
});
```

The var that I have stored into php is `$list_object`

How can I change my code to fetch object instead of a url?

Comment: can you not just json encode your php array and return it as json to the js which can then just jsondecode it and process it as usual

Comment: My array is jsonencode() but how to put inside this app instead of fetch data from external file? Can you please give me an example with that structure?

Comment: Fetching from a file is just your server tha serves static files, it's the same thing as going to an url and your server sends a JSON object.

Comment: jsut change  url: 'includes/list.json'  to the location of your php file. make sure your php file only outputs json and it'll be all fine

Comment: isn't a php file is a php variable @Dave

Comment: your php variable is created by your php script otherwise its just a string.  If i'm not understanding you'll have to have a better attempt at explainin it as it looks to me like you just want your app to read a json encoded array where the array is generated by a php file in an ajax style request basically

Comment: I don't have understand how to use my php variable instead of json into my collection, I want to populate my collection by a PHP variable to from url with same structure of app @Dave

Comment: well javascript cannot read php variables directly so you basically have to go php > json decode > send to javascript > json decode > javascript now has working array.  So as long as you follow that process be it referencing your php variable from a text file on your url or from an actual .php file it doesn't matter.  Its still effectively what is commonly called an ajax request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can't access PHP variables from javascript. After fetching some informations, the php side already finished its job. There are 2 ways to do whatever you are trying to do.

Create a collection: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection

The collection will fetch the list of objects as JSON. Each object will then be passed to a Model class. This way, you can fetch a list of objects and from this list you can create new models. Since models aren't going to get fetched using sync. A `change` event should be triggered.

The other thing you can do is to fetch specific objects. When specifying an object, it will send an ID to the php server. With this id, you can load a specific element in the list and parse it as JSON.

Again, from JS, you can only get files from a server or streams. Websocket is the only way to get long lived full duplex socket in javascript.